# Largest and smallest dodecagon with sides $1, 2, 3, \dots,12$

Tags: geometry, optimization

Of all dodecagons laying in the cartesian plane, all of whose vertices are lattice points, and whose sides are of length $1, 2, 3, \dots,$ and $12$ in some order, which two have the largest and smallest area?

Comment: Are degenerate dodecagons (with some of their internal angles being 180°) allowed?

Comment: Also, what about self-intersecting shapes?

Comment: No, degenerate dodecagons are not allowed, nor self-intersecting shapes.

Comment: Or, is it allowed that some internal angles be zero degrees?

Comment: No sir, internal angles cannot be 0.

Comment: Can the pitch of the lattice be $ < 1$ ?

Comment: Are reflex angles (greater than 180 degrees) permitted?

Comment: @BenBarden Yes, angles greater than straight allowed. Pitch must be 1.

Comment: Here are examples when sides need be in order: 1, 2, 3, ..., 12: https://oeis.org/A273089/a273089.pdf

Answer (score 15):

The smallest area I can find:

> This has an area = $40$
>
>  [image]
>
>  The area of the angled section can be seen to be
>  $ (6 \times 8 / 2) - (4 \times 3 / 2) - (3 \times 2) = 24 - 6 - 6 = 12$
>  The remainder can be counted with an area of $28$
>  $ 12 + 28 = 40$
>
>  I don't *know* this is the smallest – it is **my** smallest.
>  I found another solution without any angles, area $41$.

The largest area I can find (*another* edit):

> This has an area = $378$
>
>  This was a lot more difficult than finding a smallest area.
>  The improved solution was found by looking for an enclosing rectangle or square that would maximise the area, comprised of the available dimensions. I found the possibilities
>  $26 \times 16$ (as used in an earlier post)
>  $25 \times 17$
>  $21 \times 21$
>  So I continued with that last one.
>
>  I then juggled around the 6 smallest dimensions (apart from $5$ which I wanted on a corner) to find the least area which would be lost by using rectangles as cut-outs, and I found that the smallest area which would be lost is $33$ from those rectangular cutouts.
>
>  Along with that are two mitres at the other corners, losing another $24 + 6 = 30$ area.
>  $441 - 33 - 30 = 378$
>
>  Finally I juggled around these parts and the four remaining lengths to obtain this:
>
>  [image]
>
>  In detail, $(21 \times 21) - (6 \times 8 / 2)- (3 \times 4 / 2) - (3 \times 4) - (1 \times 7) - (2 \times 6) - (1 \times 2) = $
>  $ 441 - 24 - 6 - 12 - 7 - 12 - 2 = 378 $
>  I am fairly sure this is the largest possible - but I may be wrong.
>
>  The 5 and the 10 lengths are the only ones that can go diagonally.
>  They are the hypotenuse of Pythagorean triples $3:4:5$ and $6:8:10$.

Comment: In your biggest, What if you flip your six and seven around? ie. coming down from 9, you make the seven go to the right, then 1 down, then 6 to the left to connect to the 10? That should get you another 14 to make 221

Comment: Same thing with your 4,3,2 — connect the five down and left with a 3 going left, then 2 down, then 4 to the right to connect with the 11 — gives you another 14 I think for 235 total

Comment: Ah! I think I can do the same the other other side too. Hang on... that will take 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @El-Guest thanks for that: it gained 6+7 on the right and 6+8 on the left. But it leaves me thinking there should be yet a larger area to be found, as my original approach was wrong (apart from the angles).

Comment: @El-Guest following your input I revised the answer completely. This is a bit larger that OP's ordered example, so there could still be room for improvement, e.g. a shape that is more square in its overall dimensions.

Comment: Looks good, @WeatherVane!!

Answer (score 9):

The largest area I have found:

> Area = 378, as indicated
>  [image]

Comment: Hah! you posted this while I was busy editing the similar solution! Well done.

Answer (score 8):

Minimizing area, I present the "snake".

Should be smaller than the others found so far.

> Area = 37 [image: the snake polygon] The triangular part is a 3x4 triangle for an area of 6, minus two squares at the right angle for a total of 4. The rest are 33 squares.

Generalization of solution:

> After the parts 2,3 and 5 are used for the head, and 1 for the end, all the others can can be divided into pairs of *a* and *a+2*, and one pair of *b* and *b+1*. These pairs can all be steered to either direction, so the tail can be made to not collide with itself. This works for n-gons, where n is divisible by 4.

Daniel Mathias used this generalization for his [hexadecagon answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99424/18690)

An alternative snake with the same area:

> Area = 37 [image: alternative snake]

Comment: Very nice. I was convinced that WV's solution was optimal, and did not put much effort into finding a better minimum area.

Comment: Vey good. I didn't think mine was optimal but I've been looking in a different direction.