# A Prime Ant's Excursion in the Cartesian Plane

Tags: geometry, primes

An ant resides at the origin of the Cartesian plane. One morning she sets out on a long excursion of its first quadrant and pledges to walk a different prime number of units every day starting with 2, always in a straight line, always within the same quadrant, and always staying overnight at lattice points. Each day, the number of units she walks is the prime number immediately following the prime number of the previous day (though in a different direction so as not to walk in a straight line on two consecutive days).  At the end of her excursion, she returns home never having crossed or retraced her own path.

(Her walk will thus be a polygon of sides -in order- 2, 3, 5, 7, ..., with one of its vertices in the origin and all the others in lattice points in the first quadrant.)

a) Strictly following these rules, what is the earliest the ant can be back at the origin?

b) Can she make such excursions of any number of days greater than that minimum?

An earlier related puzzle: [An ant's walk in the Cartesian Plane](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106505/an-ants-walk-in-the-cartesian-plane)

Also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237374/lattice-n-gons-with-ordered-side-lengths-1-2-3-n

Comment: Must the points she walks to have integer coordinates? Must she walk in orthorgonal directions (ie. always N, S, E or W)?

Comment: Wheather Vane: Yes, and no. But at the end of day's walk, she must be at a lattice point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it is a moving target: the specifics keep changing, and perfectly cromulent answers (like [Nuclear Hoagie's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/123189/36023) or [mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/123195/36023)) no longer answer the question because the goalposts are no longer where they used to be at the time of writing the answer.

Comment: @Bass: I'm sorry, but that's not how it's supposed to work. You're supposed to wait to answer until a question is clear. If there are pending questions in the comments and you still decide to answer, it's on you.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That is *exactly* how it is [supposed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4355/36023) to work. That is literally what several of the close options are for. However, the close votes often don't happen quickly enough, which means we're going to get questions with non-matching answers, which is expressly [frowned upon](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6257/36023). A close vote is not a downvote, it's supposed to give OP the time to fix the question before more people spend their time answering it.

Comment: In this case, isn't the close vote now too late? Since the question is now clear (at 2023-11-16 01:38:55Z). Granted, I wasn't available when the original version of the question was up, but I can empathize with you feeling bad that an answer you've crafted is no longer valid. But I'd say, what's done is done, seems like the question is in its final version now.

Comment: @justhalf Don't think so; the currently top voted (+10) answer only answers half the question because this question is actually two questions in one post. In addition, there is no mention of whether it is now okay for the path to touch itself, as long as there's no crossing or retracing. (Also, I don't particularly mind that my answer is no longer valid; but the person reading it in 2028 will almost certainly find it annoying.)

Comment: @Bass: The question still not being clear (touching without crossing) is definitely a reason to close-vote... You didn't mention that in any comment, though, so the OP cannot know it needs to be clarified, and we cannot know it should be closed :x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer (b)

> There are **more solutions**.
>
>  The first three are
>  **7 days**: (0,0) (2,0) (2,3) (6,6) (13,6) (13,17) (0,17) (0,0)
>  **11 days**: (0,0) (2,0) (2,3) (6,6) (13,6) (13,17) (1,12) (1,29) (20,29) (20,52) (0,31) (0,0)
>  **13 days**: (0,0) (2,0) (2,3) (7,3) (7,10) (18,10) (30,15) (22,0) (41,0) (41,23) (21,44) (21,75) (9,40) (0,0)
>
>  [image]
>
>  The Pythorean primes with which we can go diagonally and stay on the lattice can be verified from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002144):
>   5, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61, 73, 89, 97, 101, 109, 113, 137, 149, 157, 173, 181, 193, 197, 229, 233, 241, 257, 269, 277, 281, 293, 313, 317, 337, 349, 353, 373, 389, 397, 401, 409, 421, 433, 449, 457, 461, 509, 521, 541, 557, 569, 577, 593, 601, 613, 617 . . .

**Edit**: I was beginning to think that there are only prime solutions, but

> the next two solutions are
>
>  **15 days**: (0,0) (2,0) (2,3) (7,3) (7,10) (18,10) (6,15) (21,23) (21,42) (44,42) (64,21) (95,21) (83,56) (43,47) (0,47) (0,0)
>
>  **17 days**: (0,0) (2,0) (2,3) (7,3) (7,10) (18,10) (18,23) (35,23) (35,42) (58,42) (78,21) (78,52) (115,52) (75,61) (75,104) (28,104) (0,59) (0,0)
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]

Comment: This looks cool. What's your method of solving?

Comment: Really beautiful!

Comment: @justhalf solved with [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), discarding anything that goes out of the quadrant, or crosses a previous line.

Comment: Hm, an interesting question would be: is it guaranteed that a solution that goes out the quadrant has an equivalent solution that does not?

Comment: @justhalf given that each solution has four rotations (one in each quadrant) then yes.

Comment: @WeatherVane that doesn't guarantee the solution doesn't need to cross quadrant boundary, though. A semi-circle with its diameter aligned to axis and center at origin has four rotations as well, but it'll always cross quadrant boundary, for example.

Comment: @justhalf then I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @WeatherVane, hmm, let's try another way. I'm asking whether is it possible that a solution exists that has the path starting with +X+Y quadrant, going to +X-Y quadrant, then back to +X+Y quadrant, then to -X+Y, before touching back the origin. I asked this because this kind of solutions would be excluded from your BFS due to "discarding anything that goes out of the quadrant".

Comment: @justhalf there are solutions that visit 3 of the 4 quadrants, but I don't know about that precise sequence.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos re part (b) – the number of solutions grows rapidly: 7 days 1, 11 days 2, 13 days 16, 15 days 66, 17 days 525, 19 days 5098... With no *touching* any part of the path, except finishing at (0,0).

Comment: @WeatherVane: These numbers certainly deserve being in the OEIS as already are their close cousins:https://oeis.org/A273089. Nice job!

Answer (score 10):

> The ant can get home in 7 days (although my ant is walking clockwise): 
>
> Day 1:  2 N     (0,2) 
> Day 2:  3 E     (3,2) 
> Day 3:  5 NE    (6,6) 
> Day 4:  7 N     (6,13) 
> Day 5:  11 E    (17,13) 
> Day 6:  13 S    (17,0) 
> Day 7:  17 W    (0,0)

> I believe this is the minimum, but don't currently have a proof.  Don't know whether they can do it again.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a (messy) picture proof of optimality for @melmackian's solution:

> [image]

Legend:

- Red lines: first 3 moves (2,3,5 units)
- Small black circles with coordinates: some lattice points at a too small prime distance from origin
- Green circles: possible positions after the fourth move (7 units)
- Blue circles with coordinates: lattice points at distance 13 from home
- Yellow circles with coordinates: lattice points at distance 17 from home

The 5th move cannot reach a blue circle from a green circle: a move of 11 units must be orthogonal, so it's enough to check green-blue pairs on the same line, and none of those are exactly 11 units apart.

The 6th move *can* reach a yellow circle with moves 11 and 13 units long: for example like this:

> [image]

(@melmackian's solution is actually a reflection of this one, and there's also another path that produces a polygon with a zero degree angle between the shortest and the longest side; I chose this one to rescue at least the tiny bit of aesthetics I could, while complying with OP's wish of going anticlockwise.)

As for question b, the answer is

> Yes.  For example:
>  [image]

Comment: Interesting, but in (b) the OP says in [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123186/a-prime-ants-excursion-in-the-cartesian-plane#comment344023_123186) "path must not be crossed over or retraced".

Comment: Comments are not part of the question though.

Comment: @Bass it is now

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your response to (b), but it seems not to satisfy the rule "At the end of her excursion, she returns home never having crossed or retraced her own path."  Though I guess that was added as a clarification after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

The ant can return home in

> 4 days. The idea is to make a 3-4-5 right triangle, using the difference of 7 and 11 to make the final 4 side:

> [image]

I'm not sure if points on the axes count as "in the first quadrant", but I think it's reasonable to permit them, as we require the origin to be the start/end point of this first quadrant tour.

Comment: doesn't the ant have to start with a walk of length 2?

Comment: @juicifer Shoot, the problem has changed a bit. At first, the ant neither needed to stop on lattice points, nor start with a side length of 2.