# On certain triplets of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory, primes

While completelely factorizing integers, my student Luciana noticed that the canonical prime factorization of the three consecutive numbers 81=3^4, 82=2x41, and 83=83, use numbers which are all different: 2,3,4,41, and 83. She would like to know the largest possible triplet of such numbers. I told her it was likely that such triplets occur infinitely often, but a matter difficult to prove.

"What then is the largest such triplet you can find?",-she asked. I told her I would pass the question to someone abler than me.

Comment: So the question is "what is the largest triplet *you* can find"? How is this not "subjectively correct answers", then?

Comment: The twin-primes conjecture immediately implies there are infinitely many such triplets.

Comment: @msh210 Not so sure. The number between the two primes might have, say, repeated exponents.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize you were including the exponents. But then your example is no good: it has repeated exponents of 1.

Comment: @msh210 I'm assuming OP means numbers > 1, since prime factorizations are unique up to multiplication by units.

Comment: @OP I don't think this is an interesting question. It most likely is unsolved, and finding the largest such triplet is likely a game of who has the most computing power.

Comment: Previous open-ended questions from OP such as the [dodecagon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99365/largest-and-smallest-dodecagon-with-sides-1-2-3-dots-12) and [hexadecagon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99415/largest-and-smallest-hexadecagon-with-sides-1-2-3-dots-16) problems asked *two* questions (smallest *and* largest area). A green check was awarded for the hexadecagon because one answer had the best of both, but the earlier question had the best areas from different answers, and so none was accepted.

Comment: @Adam Golstein Thanks Adam for your answer. Luciana is very pleased with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going with the twin primes approach, I tried the largest twin primes found to date, ($2996863034895 · 2^{1290000} \pm 1$, but $2996863034895$ factorizes to $3^2×5×18583×3583757$ which means $2$ would be both a base and an exponent. I continued this strategy.

> The second largest twin primes found to date are $3756801695685 · 2^{666669} \pm 1$. To try the same strategy again, $3756801695685$ factorizes to $3×5×43×347×16785299$. If we allow multiple exponents of 1, then this means the values can be represented the following way: $3756801695685 · 2^{666669} - 1 = $ ($200,700$ decimal digits I won't write out, but it is prime, and thus has a single factor to the power of $1$), $3756801695685 · 2^{666669}=2^{666669}×3×5×43×347×16785299$, and $3756801695685 · 2^{666669} + 1 = $ ($200,700$ decimal digits I again won't write out, but you get the deal). Therefore, all those factors are unique, and so are the non-$1$ exponents.

There are very likely infinitely many larger triplets. This is the largest I wanted to take the time to find.